# "Who is this about?" or "Whom is this about?"

Tags: whom, who

I've got a video about some famous person and I want to ask someone else "who this person is".

Would it be correct to ask:

> Who is this video about?

or

> Whom is this video about?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the correct form is "**whom** is this about?", just as you'd say "it's about **him**". In common usage, though, **whom** is dying out and, sadly, is starting to sound odd to the average English speaker.

Comment: "Whom is this video about?" does sound odd. "Whom" is _not_ dying out. The widespread use of "It's me" does _not_ mean that the word _I_ is dying out.

Comment: Well, "whom" nowadays is rarely used where it grammatically belongs. That, to me, represents dying out.

Comment: This depends on the milieu, or class, if you will, and the percentage of well-educated people among the representatives of that class. "Who does this belong to?' doesn't roll off some people's tongues easily. Philistines say "Should have went"; there are many more philistines than well-educated people. It doesn't mean that the word "gone" is suddenly dying out.

Comment: I agree with ralph.m. I think that "whom" is dying out . . .

Comment: @Ricky—problem is that even those who try to be classy usually get the usage of "whom" wrong. Most attempts to use it these days are wrong, unfortunately. It's particularly bad when mixed with -ever, as in "whomever" and "whomsoever" etc., which are almost invariably used when who is not actually an object.

Comment: The entire language is misused by the vast majority of people its native users, and always was. The fact that some of that nonsense is now on television doesn't change much. By hook or crook certain portions of society manage to speak properly and pass their standards down to the next generation every time. The process is facilitated by their aversion to television and steadfast conviction that one needs to be well-read in order to be well-spoken. A few lines of good poetry buried in one's subconscious, plus a few classic titles ("What did Hemingway write? Something about a bell?") and voila!

Comment: "portions of society manage to speak properly and pass their standards down to the next generation every time". But the masses always win, eventually. You can see this in how language degrades inevitably over time. Take languages like French, Italian, Spanish etc. All degraded versions of Latin spawned by the riffraff of the gutters of medieval Europe. :p

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, you claim you want to find out who that person in the viedeo is. Why don't you say:

> Who is the person in that video?

or if you want to practice using the dative:

> Whom is this video about?

And whom is not becoming obsolete, yet.

Answer (score -1):

"Who is this about?" is correct, as "who"  is the subject of this sentence.

"About whom is this?" would be the correct way to use "whom", as here it the object.

Comment: The subject of "Who is this about" is "this", not "who". The verb "is" is placed before the subject because of interrogative subject-verb inversion. It's the same structure as "Who were the videos about?"